# FOP sh: 1: java: not found

Tags: java, php, pdf, pdf-generation, apache-fop

on my WEBSITE I generate PDF via FOP java library, for a while it worked, but recently started throwing error:

```
FopException SH: 1: java: not found
```

which may be wrong? Is it necessary to install anything on the server? Java is installed

Comment: It seems that ```sh``` cannot find Java, try running ```java --version``` and  make sure that its [set as en environment variable](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/).

Comment: It looks like that java is not in your `path` environment variable.